# Trim if text is too long with container width

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of component like this:

```
<OverlayTrigger placement="bottom" overlay={this.nameTooltip(product.full_name)}>
  <div refs={"product_full_name_" + product.full_name}>
    {product.full_name_tag(16)} /* Trim the full_name into 16 characters */
  </div>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Now I want to change, if the `product.full_name` text can fit to its container, render it normally. If not, trim it till fit and have a tooltip. Personally, I can start with:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.resizeName()
}

componentDidUpdate() {
  this.resizeName()
}

/* Will be called after DOM is rendered */
resizeName() {
  for(ref in this.refs) {
    /* - Get ref begin with "product_full_name_" */
    /* - Check if text is overflow */
    /* - If overflow calculate number of character to fit with container */
  }
}
```

This is my starting design, if someone have any better solution please help me.

Comment: Are you against using CSS to achieve the desired result? You can truncate words with ellipses..https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Comment: I feel dump, I didn't know about this. Since you didn't tell me as an answer but a comment. I don't know how to do in this case. However, thank you!

Comment: I'll make it an answer if you feel it helped you out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you against using CSS to achieve the desired result? You can truncate words with ellipses..and in other ways! and it's much easier than this!

Check out:
developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-over‌​flow